# Blazor Web App (.Net 8) with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, windows-authentication

I have created a new Blazor Server Web App in .Net (the one that has both server and client projects). I would like to use Windows Authentication on this app but I'm not sure how I configure it. In the past I have had Blazor Server apps and run them in IIS under a service account, which worked well.  Visual Studio also used my IIS server rather than IIS Express.

But I'm not sure how I configure this on a Blazor Web App or even if its possible?

Previously I would:

Program.cs, add the below:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization()
```

Create an application in IIS that pointed to my Blazor Server app.

My Visual Studio launchSettings.json is below

```json
{
  "$schema": http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json,
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": true,
      "anonymousAuthentication": false,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": http://localhost:46190,
        "sslPort": 0
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": http://localhost/OppsSupport,
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But none of this seems to work, I noticed when you create a new Blazer Web App, "Windows" does not appear in the drop down list for authentication.

I get an error of

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().'

I tried adding the below, but no joy:

```cs
app.UsePathBase("/OppsSupport");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA

UPDATE 1
I managed to get Windows Authentication working via IIS by using the below in my launchsetting.json file:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/OppsSupport" 
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/OppsSupport/" 
    }
  }
}
```

However when I now launch my app it loses all CSS and images and when I click a href I get a 404 as it does not remember the virtual directory I'm in.

It goes to `http://localhost/counter`
Rather than `http://localhost/OppsSupport/Counter`

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps these links may help you:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/17vyxji/windows_authentication_in_blazor_8/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/15mjdak/dotnet8_win_auth/

EDIT:
for the PathBase, try modifing the tag in App.razor

```
<base href="/YOURPATH" />
```